# 'decimal' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: invalid decimal Unicode string

Tags: python, django

UnicodeEncodeError at /post/
I have two questions.
'decimal' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: invalid decimal Unicode string

```
    Request Method: POST
    Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/
    Django Version: 1.7.7
    Python Executable: C:\Python27\python.exe
    Python Version: 2.7.8

    Traceback:
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
      111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
      69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
      29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
      57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
      25.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\braces\views\_forms.py" in dispatch
      22.         return super(CsrfExemptMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\braces\views\_ajax.py" in dispatch
      142.             request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\braces\views\_ajax.py" in dispatch
      76.             return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "E:\git\statistics\main\views.py" in post_ajax
      174.                 handleCity(data, department)
    File "E:\git\statistics\main\views.py" in handleCity
      48.         o = CityTable.objects.get(city=department)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
      92.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
      345.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
      691.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
      709.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
      1331.         clause, require_inner = self._add_q(where_part, self.used_aliases)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
      1358.                     current_negated=current_negated, connector=connector)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_filter
      1225.                                                     lookups, value)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py" in get_lookup_constraint
      1561.                     lookup_class(Col(alias, target, source), val), AND)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py" in __init__
      82.         self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py" in get_prep_lookup
      85.         return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_lookup(self.lookup_name, self.rhs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_lookup
      646.             return self.get_prep_value(value)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_value
      915.         return int(value)



  url:"/post/",
            type:"POST",
            //{'type':$("#type").val(),'data':blank_data_all,'department':department}
            data:JSON.stringify({
                type:$("#type").val(),
                data:blank_data_all,
                department:$("#dept").val()
            }),
            cache:false,
            contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dateType:"json",
```

department    fill in Chinese , being given back above.
I try encode("utf-8")  as above error。
2 Q
There is a problem, the Django model object how the assignment.
Like

```
dept= "Chinese"
o=City ()
o[dept]
```

o[dept] will a error. Can only use o.dept assignment? City () there are a lot of projects, I'd like to make one from acquisition to the values of the cyclic assignment.

Like this

```
City     {"i1":"xxx","i2":"xxx"........}
city['i1']=....
city['i2']=....
```

THX
Two  questions.

Comment: Well first off, of you have 2 questions, ask 2 separate questions. Secondly, what is the string you're trying to parse?

Comment: {"type":"city","data":[{"i1":"1"},{"i2":"1"},{"i3":"1"},{"i4":"1"},{"i5":"1"},{"i6":"1"},{"i7":"1"},{"i8":"1"},{"i9":"1"},{"i10":"1"},{"i11":"1"},{"i12":"1"},{"i13":"1"},{"i14":"1"},{"i15":"1"},{"i16":"1"},{"i17":"1"},{"i18":"1"},{"i19":"1"},{"i20":"11"},{"i21":"1"},{"i22":"1"},{"i23":"1"},{"i24":"1"},{"i25":"1"},{"i26":"1"},{"i27":"1"},{"i28":"1"},{"i29":"1"},{"i30":"1"},{"i31":"1"},{"i32":"1"},{"i33":"1"},{"i34":"1"},{"i35":"1"},{"i36":"1"},{"i37":"1"},{"i38":"1"},{"i39":"1"},{"i40":"1"},{"i41":"1"},{"i42":"1"},{"i43":"1"},{"i44":"1"},{"i45":"1"}],"department":"澶師"}

Comment: t = self.request_json[u"type"]
            data = self.request_json[u"data"]
            department = self.request_json[u"department"]